# Can you keep the statue at the end?

Tags: dishonored-2

I read somewhere that you could keep the statue of

> your last known family member

at the end of the game and rule with it by your side. But other than a seemingly random statement, I can't find any other reference to it, let alone actually doing it.

Can this actually be done?

Comment: Typing >! Allows you to hide spoilers. Please make your question less vague

Comment: @George Willcox: I added a small piece of info, but other than that the question seems fine actually.

Comment: @BoltClock I've never played the dishonored games, and so don't know what the question is asking about, it's only as the asker said that the question was intentionally vague.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to do this in

> high chaos

after

> eliminating Delilah either lethally or non-lethally

by

> going to the throne and interacting with it.

You will be given the option to claim it for yourself, leaving them cast in stone.

Note that you will not be given this option if

> your overall chaos is low.

Comment: AH OK. Apparently I didn't kill enough my first time thru. New Game+ playthru will allow me to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes. By sitting in the throne yourself.